# two users using same account, same code at same database but have different result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

there are two database, DB1 for userA and DB2 for userB. A need get data from DB2 and A ask B for support.
B use sql like below

```
select t.column1, t.column2, m.column3
from   view1 t, table1 m
```

and view1 statement like below

```
select a.column4, b.column5
from   view2 a, table2 b
```

B was granted view1 for userA and testing in DB1 by using userA account, like below

```
select t.column1, t.column2, m.column3
from   view1@lnk2db2 t, table1@lnk2db2 m
```

B's testing result shows information.
but when A using same code, it only shows column but no data.

Question :

1. by using same account, same code and compiled at same database and same time, did any reader(you) have the same experience?
2. B only grant view1 to A but view2 not, is this the critical point?

**thanks for your support and please let me know when any place didn't describe clearly.**

Comment: It was fix, there's a view have function "USERENV", thanks for everybody who you ever read this writing and wish you have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a [Virtual Private Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm)? In that case, it's possible for two users to see different results when querying the same table.

Comment: I'm not sure, because it happened in office. i'll try to trace, thanks for your suggestion.